# Execute sed command inside TCL script

Tags: sed, tcl

I am trying to execute sed command inside TCL  script . Basically i wanted to remove all empty lines from the input file before reading the file using TCL. so i tried  following in my script

```
 exec sed -i '/^\s*$/d' .tmp.PG_Ring
 set fid [open ".tmp.PG_Ring" r]
```

But the script is dumping following Error .

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `''
while executing
"exec sed -i '/^\s*$/d' .tmp.PG_Ring"
(file "pg_ring.tcl" line 1)
```

could you please provide me work around for this & help me with best way to do this?

Comment: Can you give this a try `sed -i 's/\s*//'`?

Comment: i am able to execute sed -i '/^\s*$/d' .tmp.PG_Ring command successfully on shell but its not working inside  TCL script

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That won't work, as single quotes have *no* special meaning to Tcl at all. Tcl uses braces to mean the same sort of thing (except they nest nicely), so instead you can use this:.

```
exec sed -i {/^\s*$/d} .tmp.PG_Ring
```